# installing Partisan Telegram

Tags: android, android-studio, telegram

I'm looking to install Partisan Telegram but don't know how to properly use Android Studio, SDK, or NDK, I've simply never used them before.

https://github.com/wrwrabbit/Partisan-Telegram-Android#readme

I've downloaded Android Studio on PC and cloned the above link but I'm just lost on the rest of this (see image).

[ich bin vollidiot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABGd6.png)

I looked around in here for "TMessagesProj/config", but can't find it, idk what I'm doing tbh.

[Within the highlighted I looked through everything but can't find anything going by"config"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X72JL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can just download the PTelegram.apk from the release page on your Android device and install it

https://github.com/wrwrabbit/Partisan-Telegram-Android/releases

This was the latest version
https://github.com/wrwrabbit/Partisan-Telegram-Android/releases/download/3.1.0/PTelegram.apk

Comment: Thanks man, I'm actually retarded.

Comment: Always nice to accidentally learn Android development ;)
You could also mark the answer as solved so no more need to answer!